# How to add a css class to <td> tags in a kv- GridView class in Yii2

Tags: yii2

I'm Using Kartik's GridView Widget,

```
GridView::widget([
            'id'=>'crud-datatable',
            'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
            'filterModel' => $searchModel,
            'pjax'=>true,
            'contentOptions' => ['class' => 'form-control punjabi'],
            'headerOptions' => ['class' => 'text-center'],
            'columns' => require(__DIR__.'/_columns.php'),
])
```

In yii\grid\GridView class, It can be done with the following options :

```
[
    'contentOptions' => ['class' => 'text-center'],
    'headerOptions' => ['class' => 'text-center']
],
```

But using the above options in Kartik's GridView Class generates error: Undefined Property `contentoptions`.

How to go About this?

Comment: use `containerOptions`.

Comment: just for information, which class is $containerOptions a property of kartik\grid\GridView or yii\grid\GridView?

Answer (score 3):

[`contentOptions`](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-grid-column.html#$contentOptions-detail) is an attribute of `yii\grid\Column` not of `yii\grid\GridView`. The classes need to be applied to the columns i.e.

```
GridView::widget([
    ... //Other options here
    'columns' => [
        [
            'attribute' => 'name',
            'contentOptions' => ['class' => 'form-control punjabi'],
            'headerOptions' => ['class' => 'text-center'],
        ]
    ]
]
```

If you would like to apply the same style to all the cells you can create your own column class, set defaults for `contentOptions` and `headerOptions`, and use that class instead of `yii\grid\DataColumn`.

Comment: $headerOptions only styles the Header. How do I edit the css of the Filter Cells?

Comment: When in doubt refer to the manual: [$filterOptions](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-grid-column.html#$filterOptions-detail) or  [$filterInputOptions](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-grid-datacolumn.html#$filterInputOptions-detail)